# Will redesigning my site hurt my SEO if my URLs and content stay the same but the DOM structure of pages changes radically?

Tags: seo, wordpress, html, redesign

I have a great working WordPress site that I make money from because the SEO has been perfect for ages now. I really want to redesign the site (the design is 12 years old now) and I want to use Elementor.

The URLs will stay exactly the same and the content will stay mostly the same, but the "DOM" structure will be changing a lot (mainly because Elementor adds tons of DOM elements.

So will this affect my SEO?

Comment: "Elementor adds tons of DOM elements" - Is that _tons_ of wasteful/unnecessary DOM elements that bloat the HTML like many WYSIWYG editors?

Comment: Yes it is :) wasteful & unnecessary. but it save's me days of work.

Comment: If the new page is considerably heavier (loads slower) you might see a small drop, but if you are already ranking really well as you said, then you probably won't see any drops - quite contrary, you might see some improvements because of the better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to check if the loading time change (TTFB mostly).
Iif it stay the same, your SEO won't be hurt. The technical part on a webpage isn't the major part of the seo algorythm.
Just be sure the structure of your webpage keep the same

- using of meta data
- H1, H2, Hn structure